# Updates made to users session data in Ajax are lost after ajax returns

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, session

I am using an Ajax call to update a users data and to also store the value in the session.

(Please note I am not talking about storing sessions in databases here).

In the ajax controller I make a call like this:

```
$this->session->userdata['user']['email'] = 'some_new_email@blah.com';
```

and then to test that it has worked I say:

```
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

and I can clearly see that the session has been updated as expected.

However, once I have returned from the ajax controller I then say:

```
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

and the value of the session variable which I have just updated has returned to its previous (old) state.

QUESTION:

Why oh why is this happenning and how do I fix it?

Any suggestions welcome..

CODE:

1) jquery ajax call posts user data to here:
The data is then sent to the api where it is validated (again) and then updated in the database. $response is the result of the api call (the updated user object in json format):

```
$response = $account_repository->update_email($update_email_entity);

if($response['status']['code']==200)
    {
        // [Update users email in database was a success, now update session to reflect changes]:
        $this->session->userdata['users']['email'] = $response['payload']['email'];
        print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
    }
    else ...
```

2) The print_r above shows that the session has been updated correctly.
After the ajax has returned I then refresh the page (there is a print_r on the page which contains all of the users session data).
The session data has not been updated.

INFO:

My ajax controller function is just another function in the account controller.  Other functions in this same controller make updates to the session and everything works fine. It is just when the controller function is accessed via ajax that I have this problem.

Has anyone seen this problem before?  Any suggestions on fixing it?

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Seems like you'r using CodeIgniter framework, if so try: $this->session->set_userdata('email', 'new@email.com');

Comment: I have added some code above - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe session_regenerate_id is your problem. Your XHR call regenerate the sessionId without deleting the old session file. The next call works with old session_id by cookie.

For example..
When an AJAX is done, sessionId is updated and a new one is generated and maybe updated in the database but the cookie in the browser is not updated, so the next time browser requests a new page it sends a cookie with the wrong session id and the session becomes invalid or retrieved old data.